# Vue Apollo Query not overwritting local data

Tags: vue.js, apollo

I have a modal that is using import() to dynamically render content. The modal has a form that gets its fields populated by a Query. The data shows up correctly. If I modify the data and close the modal and come back to it, my changes are still there.

So it is almost like the query isn't running after the initial render of the component. I would like to destroy any change that were made.

Here is the Component

```html
<template>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <loader v-if="$apollo.loading"
      :width="100"
      :height="100"></loader>

    <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
      <button type="button"
        class="close"
        @click="closeModal()">
        <i class="nc-icon nc-simple-remove"></i>
      </button>
      <h4 class="title title-up">Edit User</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>

        <fg-input
          label="Name"
          v-model="user.name"
          v-validate="modelValidations.name"
          :error="getError('name')"
          name="name"
          type="text">
        </fg-input>

        <fg-input
          label="Email"
          v-model="user.email"
          v-validate="modelValidations.email"
          :error="getError('email')"
          name="email"
          type="email">
        </fg-input>

        <fg-input
          label="Role">
          <el-select class="select-default"
                    v-model="user.role"
                    placeholder="Select Role">
            <el-option v-for="option in roles"
                      class="select-default"
                      :value="option.name"
                      :label="option.name"
                      :key="option.name">
            </el-option>
          </el-select>
        </fg-input>

        <fg-input
          label="Active">
          <p-switch v-model="user.active" type="success" on-text="ON" off-text="OFF" ref="active"></p-switch>
        </fg-input>

      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="left-side">
        <p-button type="neutral" @click="validate()">Submit</p-button>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="right-side">
        <p-button type="neutral" @click.native="closeModal()">Close</p-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
  //Components
  import {Switch} from '@/components/UIComponents'

  //Mixins
  import {notification} from '@/mixins/notification.js'
  import {validation} from '@/mixins/form-validation.js'
  import {userValidation} from '@/mixins/users/user-validation.js'

  //Queries
  import editUser from '@/queries/users/edit-user-mutation.gql'
  import users from '@/queries/users/users-query.gql'
  import getUser from '@/queries/users/user-query.gql'
  import getRoles from '@/queries/roles/roles-query.gql'

    export default {
        name: 'edit-user',
        components: {
          [Switch.name]: Switch
        },
        mixins: [notification, validation, userValidation],
        props: {
          'modalData': {
            required: true
          }
        },
        data(){
          return {
            user: {
              id: -1,
              name: '',
              active: false,
              role: '',
              email: ''
            },
            roles: []
          }
        },
        apollo: {
          user: {
            query: getUser,
            variables() {
              return {
                id: this.modalData
              }
            },
            fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',

            //Error
            error(error) {
              console.log(error)
              this.notification('danger', this.messages.error)
            }

          },
          roles: {
            query: getRoles,

            //Error
            error(error) {
              console.log(error)
              this.notification('danger', this.messages.error)
            }
          }
        },
        created() {
          console.log('EditUser Created')
        },
        destroyed() {
          console.log('EditUser Destroyed')
        },
        methods: {
          submit() {
            this.$apollo.mutate({
              mutation: editUser,
              variables: this.user,
            })
            .then(response => {
              this.notification('success', this.messages.success)
              this.closeModal()
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              this.notification('danger', this.messages.error)
            })
          },
          closeModal() {

            //Reset local data
            //this.resetLocal()

            this.$emit('close')

          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Do I need to just override the data properties with the Apollo cache value? I could probably do this in the mounted() hook. You would think since a query is added to the component it would run everytime the component is created

Answer (score 0):

You can refetch the query each time the component is created by adding a `created` hook :

```
created() {
    this.$apollo.queries.user.refetch();
}
```

Here, `user` is the name of the query, which is the identifier in your `apollo: {}` object.